# Nginx reverse proxy for HTTPS traffic (through uWSGI socket) and websockets

Tags: sockets, nginx, flask, uwsgi

I have Nginx set up as a reverse proxy for a Flask Application running on uWSGI. The configuration looks like:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name subdomain.app.org;

  location / {
    include uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_pass unix:/home/ubuntu/app/myapp.sock;
  }
}
```

Additionally, I want to access a websocket running on the same machine on port 3232. So I changed the config to:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name subdomain.app.org;

  location /ws/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3232;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    proxy_read_timeout 86400;
  }

  location / {
    include uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_pass unix:/home/ubuntu/app/myapp.sock;
  }
}
```

When I try to access the socket from remote using `wscat -c ws://subdomain.app.org/ws` I receive `error: Error: unexpected server response (301)`.

Everything works fine when I set the location of the websocket as well as the Flask app to `/`, but then I cannot access my Flask application anymore.

Any ideas? I undestand that many people before me have asked this but not in connection with a uWSGI socket running. I have spent hours reading stackoverflow posts on this but didn't find anything suitable. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I moved away from this idea in the end. Let me know if you find a solution! Thanks

Comment: I set up my nginx to generate a self-signed certificate. Then I redirect the traffic via http to the uwsgi application. Works as expected. uwsgi does not need to handle ssl, because the reverse proxy is already responsible for it.